# pass parameter to another component - null

Tags: flutter, dart

Follow the excerpt that I send and the other that I receive the parameter. but it's coming null

```
Usuario usuario = Usuario();
        usuario.email = email;
        usuario.senha = senha;

        //cadastrar ou logar
        if( _cadastrar ){
          print(usuario);
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/termos-aceite', arguments: usuario.email);
        }else{
          //Logar
          _logarUsuario(usuario);
        }
```

// second screen
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
    setState(() {
      args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    });
    print('args');
    print(args); //value is null
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to send a map not a property

```
Usuario usuario = Usuario();
    usuario.email = email;
    usuario.senha = senha;

    //cadastrar ou logar
    if( _cadastrar ){
      print(usuario);
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/termos-aceite', arguments: {"email":usuario.email});
    }else{
      //Logar
      _logarUsuario(usuario);
    }
```

when you try to get the values cast the arguments as Map of String Object like this and and use the property key you to get the data

```
     setState(() {
  args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, Object>;

});
print('args');
print(args["email"]); //value is email's value
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better and generic approach to do that, and I would suggest you to do that.

So we can do this via using the Constructor method, which accepts some variable with values, in your case this is the page, i.e., `/termos-aceite`. Now taking the Page name as `Termos` for this `/termos-aceite`. Let us see how this works.

```
class Termos extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Todo.
  final dynamic email;

  // In the constructor, require a Todo.
  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.email}) : super(key: key);

  //To use that, you can simply do
  print(args);
  setState(() {
    args = this.email;
  });
}
```

And In order to pass it to the page, in this case to `Termos`, we do this using your code only

```
Usuario usuario = Usuario();
usuario.email = email;
usuario.senha = senha;

//cadastrar ou logar
if( _cadastrar ){
   print(usuario);
   // Read about MaterialPageRoute() here
   // https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute-class.html
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => Termos(email: email)
   ));
}else{
  //Logar
  _logarUsuario(usuario);
}
```

I hope you will get it what you want. Also, please keep googling these things about flutter. It is cool, and you will find great things there in the documentation itself. I am anyway listing down some of the links for you, hope that would be a learning experience for you. Keep learning

- [Flutter Dev Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs)
- [Naivgate With Argument](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)
- [Passing data to a new screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

Comment: thank's for help, but 
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var args = '';
    setState(() {
      args = this.email;
    });

this.email is not accessible

Comment: @usr123123 Answer edited, if the main task is to pas the email variable, which you are storing inside `usuario.email`, just pass the `email` to it, and get the value in the next page. Please try the updates answer